# How can I transfer std::multimap data over socket

Tags: c++, sockets, stl

I have a **std::multimap** variable containing key-value data, and want to transfer it to a remote server over socket.

I known, in Java, we can serialize the object as byte stream and transfer it.
However, can I do the same thing in C++?
If not, how can I transfer **std::multimap** data over socket in C++?

Meanwhile, are there some other methods to transfer **std::multimap** data over socket without serialization, or using 3rd library?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serialization of STL Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422399/serialization-of-stl-class)

Comment: @RawN, I  was also wondering whether there is some other ways to transfer a STL container without using a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done through [boost::serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html), STL collection of it can be found [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#stl)

Comment: I was also wondering whether there is some other ways to transfer a STL container without using a 3rd party library.

Comment: @ignorer : I am not aware of it.